# Display Selected Categories on OpenCart Homepage

Tags: php, opencart2.x

Is it possible to display only selected Categories with their name and link to the category on OpenCart v2.0 homepage?

[Here is a the example about how I want to display them](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UHWTX.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

yes you can done it by making your own module. if you are not familiar with creating custom module [visit this tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/from-beginner-to-advanced-in-opencart-module-development--cms-21873) it will help you on this